# How to assign colors to a variable in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'm having some trouble assigning colors to a variable in plotly. I want TRUE to be assigned to red, and FALSE to be assigned to black. What seems to happen is that the first instance is assigned to red, so if I change the ordering, the coloring also changes.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(3, 5, -1)
z <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
data <- data_frame(x, y, z)
plot_ly(data, x = x, y = y, type = "bar", color = z, colors = c("red", "black"))
```

Then I get the following:
[Plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UVOa.png)

But when I reorder the variables I get the following:

```
data %>% arrange(desc(y)) %>%
plot_ly (x = x, y = y, type = "bar", color = z, colors = c("red", "black"))
```

[Plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmKdP.png)

As you can see the coloring of TRUE and FALSE changes. Is there a way to assign each color to each variable, something like TRUE = "red", FALSE = "black"?

Comment: how about this? `data[data$z == TRUE]$col <-  "red"`  `data[data$z == FALSE]$col <-  "black"` and `colors = data$col` in your plot function

Comment: what should color be in this case? should it still be z or should it be col now? it doesn't seem to work either way...

Comment: or you could do `data$color <- ifelse(z, "red", "black")` to get a column containing colors, and then instead of the c("red","black") you put data$color

Comment: it worked when I did data$col[data$z == TRUE], and arranged the data by y (it didn't work without the arrange for some reason). thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly too late, but in case someone has the same issue, this is what works for me:

```
Global.df$color[Global.df$Region.of.Risk == "Others"] <-  "#E5E7E9"
```